# How do you send multiple parameters in a Url.Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-5.0

How do you send multiple parameters in an `Url.Action`?

I have a controller with an action, and I want 2 parameters, but the 2nd parameter is not being received.

My code is:

```
@Url.Action("Products", "Jquery", new { categoryid = 1, Productid = 2})

Publc Action Jquery(int categoryid ,int Productid)
{

}
```

but I only receive `categoryid`, every time `Productid` is null.

Please suggest to me what to do?

Comment: You are specifying the `categoryid` as a string, yet in the `Jquery` action method the signature uses an `int` for `categoryid`. Try `new { categoryid = 1, Productid = 2 }`

Comment: i'm not sure if it is a typo but the return type should be `ActionResult` and the parameter is mixed.. should be `@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", "object params")`

Comment: @robwaminal Can you tell me How to use " object params " here?

Comment: you are correct on your object params but it seems like the `actionName` which is `Jquery` is interchanged with the `controllerName` which is `Products` i pressume

Comment: yes Products is controller and Jquery is action name, now i want to send 2 parameter,but 2nd para is not receive in action.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try it like this.

```
@Url.Action("Jquery", "Products", new { @categoryid = 1, @Productid = 2})

public ActionResult Jquery(int categoryid, int Productid)
{
    return View();
}
```

you should get the 2 parameters in your action.  Assuming the `Jquery` Action is under `ProductController`

Comment: i had try this but it's not working,can't receive 2nd para. it's always null

Comment: adding `@` on your param object parameters should solve the problem

Comment: actually, it doesn't matter, if you prefix your param with `@` or not.  It still works the first one.  I'm not sure how to explain it.  Maybe you got some typo error?

Comment: I have the same problem and this didn't work for me, actually, the problem is that it builds the url adding special characters like this:
/Controller/Action?param1=foo&amp;param2=fooo

Answer (score 23):

Were you calling this action from JQuery? Sounds like you could be from the symptoms (or at least @roberto could be); if so wrap it in `Html.Raw`:

```
@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Jquery", "Products", new { @categoryid = 1, @Productid = 2}));
```

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't have to add `@` for the variable names

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, added the @'s and didn't work.

What worked for me was the `@Html.Raw` instruction.

```
@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Jquery", "Products", new { categoryid = 1, Productid = 2}))

public ActionResult Jquery(int categoryid, int Productid)
{
    return View();
}
```

In this way you can get all parameters in the controller, not only the first.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I too only had luck with the `Html.Raw` function around it. Adding `@` doesn't appear to help when called from jQuery.
Here's how it worked on a page when working with jsTree.

```
    $.ajax({
        cache: false, 
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("GetGenTreeData", "Documents", new { folder = "Docs", treeTitle = "Listed Board Documents" }))',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#docTree').jstree({
                'core': {
                    'data': data
                }
            });
        },
```