# How to pass some parameters in Url.Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person", new { id = 6, name = "rachel", grade="a" });
```

When I get the parameters in the action, I get only the first value (value of `id`), but I don't get the values of `name` and `grade`. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178320/how-to-send-multiple-parameter-in-url-action

Comment: Post your controller

Comment: public ActionResult Person(int id=0,string name=" ",string grade=" ")
        {
            return PartialView("Success");
        }

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the additional parameters on the controller method like so:

```
 public ActionResult SuccessfulPostData(int id, string name, string grade)
        {

            ViewBag.name= name;
            return View();
        }
```

In the View you can display the value:

```
 @Viewbag.name
```

Also sometimes you need to explicitly define route parameters. This is found in the RouteConfig.cs file.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}/{grade}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "SuccessfulPostData", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional, grade = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```